# Formula for projection of electric field onto plane

Tags: electromagnetism, vectors, vector-fields

Suppose I have a vector field (for example an electric field $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$, where $\mathbf{r}$ is a point in space), and also a plane with normal $\hat{n}$ which passes through a point $\mathbf{p}$. How do I find the projection of this vector field onto the plane? I think the answer might simply be $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})\times \hat{n}$ but then this doesn't use the point $\mathbf{p}$ at all. I know this question is maybe better suited for the math stackexchange but it's for an electromagnetic application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component of $\mathbf{E}$ along the normal $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is given by $(\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}) \mathbf{\hat{n}}$. So the component of $\mathbf{E}$ along the plane is simply $\mathbf{E} - (\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}}) \mathbf{\hat{n}}$. The point $\mathbf{p}$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise solution.

Comment: don't you use $${\bf E} = {\bf E}({\bf p})$$ in the above equation?

Comment: @JEB No, the plane doesn't need to pass through any specific point. In fact, there doesn't need to be a plane at all. The entire problem can be re-expressed as finding the component of $\mathbf{E}$ that is perpendicular to the vector $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$. Therefore, there is no need to use any specific point.